# ASP.Net; How to ignore or remove the Forms Authentication cookie when using Basic Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication, basic-authentication

I have a web forms asp.net website, and I am trying to bolt on an API.
I have managed to add some code in Global.ASAX Application_AuthenticateRequest() to spot URL's starting with API, such that API requests correctly route to Web API 2 controllers.

I create a security principal in Application_AuthenticateRequest(), and I use [Authorize] attribute to block unauthenticated access to the API classes.

I think a cookie is still being used though.  Once I have authenticated one API request, via the browser challenge, I am not challenged again.  I have to close the browser to force the browser to drop the cookie, and only on a new instance of the browser do I get a challange.

It is not a big problem, but it is something that I should know about and be able to control.  I am aware that this has only come about because I am using Forms Auth by default, because this started as a forms project, and is mutating into forms+basic.

How can I get the basic authentication flow going so that the forms cookie details are (conditionally) removed, or ignored?

IDE is VisualStudio 2015 Community, project is ASP.Net + WebAPI2, targetting .Net 4.6.1, running under IIS 7.5, on Win Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is through authentication.form.timeout in web.config. you can set a small value to expire the cookie. Otherwise, you have to implement your authentication filter. [This article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will have to take a look at the article, have just skimmed it and it looks like something similar.